# 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine - Oracle Database Client 12C

Tags: oracle

I have some problem with connect to the Oracle Database by Oracle Client. I installed on laptop oracle client - version 32 bit. I can connect to the database from laptop when i use 64 bit applications, but when i will use 32 bit application i get following error:

```
 ERROR System.InvalidOperationException: The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at EconLib.Utility.SqlDataAccess.OpenConnection(String host, String database, String user, String pass)
```

i have seen this question 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903366/oraoledb-oracle-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine', but i can't find oraOLEDBXX.dll on my laptop. Any idea what can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

From comment by [Wernfried Domscheit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32815/wernfried-domscheit):

> Have a look at this instruction to install both 32 bit and 64 bit on one machine: [stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100). Note Oracle OLEDB provider is not included in Oracle Instant client, you have to install it separately or enable the corresponding option in Oracle Universal Installer.